# facebook graph api Query Unsupported get request code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can someone help me with an answer?
Why some pages in Facebook Graph returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

page exists at: https://www.facebook.com/RoyalCaninRomania
and facebook graph return: http://graph.facebook.com/RoyalCaninRomania or graph.facebook.com/669235549759213

but in developer is all fine:
developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=669235549759213
he generate graph.facebook.com/669235549759213 url, but this url generate error message in browser

Comment: Trying to access your page in my browser redirects me to the FB home page, so most likely you page is not published or has restrictions in place.

Comment: Is not my page, is published, can i find somehow what restrictions has a facebook page?

Comment: Yes, I also met this case. I can not execute with my post id.

Comment: I've got similar problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly fine with me.
I believe this issue is closed.
here is the link : http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/146337548715685